# Laravel5.3 maatwebsite/excel Read value from excel & insert into database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, maatwebsite-excel

Here is my Excel data sheet type:

[image]

Here is My Table Schema:

[image]

> Here is my method to import data:

```
public function saveActivationInfoExcel(Request $request)
    {

        if($request->hasFile('import_file')){
            $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();

            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {})->get();

            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){

                foreach ($data->toArray() as $key => $value) {
                    if(!empty($value)){
                        foreach ($value as $v) {        
                            $insert[] = [
                                        'mobile_no' =>$v['mobile_no'], 
                                        'model' => $v['model'],
                                        'serial_1' => $v['serial_1'],
                                        'serial_2' => $v['serial_2'],
                                        'activation_date' => $v['activation_date'],
                                        ];
                        }
                    }
                }

                dd($insert);
                if(!empty($insert)){
                    //ProductActivationInfo::insert($insert);
                    return back()->with('success','Insert Record successfully.');
                }

            }

        }

        return back()->with('error','Please Check your file, Something is wrong there.');
    }
```

### Now my problem is, when I try to import data I got this dd($insert) error

```
Illegal string offset 'mobile_no'

'serial_1' => '3.5194508009307E+14', 
'serial_2' => '3.5194508009307E+14', 
'activation_date' => object(Carbon), null)
```

have a look both serial_1 & serial_2 showing different value rather then actual excel value. also activation_date value is null.

would appreciate your valuable suggestion to solve this regarding reading data using "maatwebsite/excel" laravel library.

Comment: Are you using .xls or .csv? I believe using .csv will solve the issue... :)

Comment: checkout the date format you insert it should be mysql :yyyy/m/d i think not sure

Answer (score -1):

Please **use the CSV file to import data** and change the serial_1 and serial_2 column format as a **fraction**. And change the format of activation_date column.

Thanks